# What are the Server Requirements for BluePrism tool with 5 Bots?

Tags: server, architecture, blueprism, rpa

The Company that I work for is planning to purchase BluePrism tool, we are in-need of the server requirements (RAM size,HD size etc) for the functioning 5 Bots.

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The Automation Platform required depends of the nature of your automations.

You can run everything in a single node and 8G of RAM and 4 Cores will be enough (if you are not automating applications that require many resources) and if you do not need to run anyhing concurrently.

On the other hand for Production purposes:

1. 1 Blue Prism Application Server 2012 R2 (This is used to Orchestrate
   your Platform)... regularly I put at least 8G RAM and 4 Cores, HDD
   used for BP is insifnificant 10G after OS installation should be
   good.

   - 1 SQL Server (where the structure of your automation, and the execution logs will be allocated) at least 8G RAM and HDD depends of
     your transacctions, logging and other configurations that you will
     choose when you automate.

     - 1 Interactive Client, (where you will monitor your platform) 4G Ram 50G HDD
   - 1 Runtime Resource (where your automations will run)... here you have to take in consideration all the resources that will be used by
     your automation, here you have to deal with that HDD Space, and
     Processor Needs. You can only run 1 automation at time, so if you
     need to run 5 different automations (what I think that you called
     robots) concurrently, you need 5 runtime resources, each one must
     have installed the required applications (used to run its
     automation)